# How to construct the following matrix elegantly in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Suppose I have a 5 dimensional matrix `v` and now I want a new matrix `D` fulfilling

```
D[a, b, n, m, d] = v[a, b, n, n, d]-v[a, b, m, m, d].
```

How do I elegantly do this in numpy?

Comment: What's the mapping criteria to go from `v` (5D) to `D` (4D)? Some sort of reduction/ diagonal summing?

Comment: I showed mapping rule in the original post. Any ambiguities？

Comment: Sorry, I don't see it. Hope I don't need an eye checkup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `einsum` can do this:

```
D = np.einsum('abiic->abic', v)[..., None, :] - np.einsum('abiic->abic', v)[:, :, None, ...]
```

Comment: Wasn't `v` `5D`? With this einsum notation of `'aiib` it seems you have `v` as `4D` instead.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to change the dimensionality? You can reshape it like this

```
import numpy as np

a, b, n, d = 2, 3, 4, 5
v = np.zeros((a, b, n, n, d))
D = v.reshape((a, b, n*n, d))
```